# Tools to make HTML/CSS work easier

Tags: html, css, interface

I need to make an web interface for employees of a company to use. I don't have a person designated to doing design or markup, and they don't really need to be anything spectacular. Nonetheless, I would rather not focus too much time on markup and styles.

I'm wondering if there are any tools or techniques which can make this easier. It could be a WYSIWYG, or some kind of intermediary markup, but the end result should be clean simple HTML/CSS. I'm open to anything right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Write it by hand - it's the only way to get clean, simple, valid and *semantic* HTML and CSS.

If you're willing to forgo the semantics, you may want to look into a CSS framework, to take care of some of the layout busywork. I am not a fan of them, but I've heard others find them quite useful. [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) and [960.gs](http://960.gs/) are the two I hear about most frequently.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but some of the garbage I've seen produced *when people don't know what they're doing* is far worse than the at least *predictably wrong* stuff you get with a WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bunch of sites, offering you clean html templates for free, like:

http://www.free-css.com/
http://www.freecsstemplates.org/
http://www.opendesigns.org/

You can edit those templates, and make everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [zen coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/)

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE gives you very clean HTML output, even when you paste word to it

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php

Its easy to implement, but if you want some kind of CMS try `Wordpress` it is very good for simple sites

http://wordpress.org/

Comment: This is really a terrible idea. Designing the whole template and styling in javascript WYSIWYG editor, are out of your mind? TinyMCE is made for a really different thing..

Comment: My mistake, I wrongly understand the question. But about CMS he can still try Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with @Karpie, but if you want to make your life with CSS easier you can try some CSS framework, there are many of them out there. I recommend you [960.gs](http://960.gs/) or something like that for layout. Check it out.